# avoid username by registration in FOSuserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

When I try to register two user with the same name.I get the message that this name exists already with fosbundle.My question is how to avoid that?

Comment: Do you mean same username or same first and last name?

Comment: Username is supposed to be unique.

Comment: Yes but it's somehow strange.How can I avoid that? because I can have 10000 of same username

Comment: Username+password is what allows a user to login. How can you possibly have 10000 users with the same username?

Comment: they will login with there emails, can you imagine one sites using username to login?

Comment: Are you serious??? There are plenty sites where you can login with username/password. One examle - www.americanexpress.com

Comment: Yes Yes I know, But If you search you name in facebook You find 10 at least having your name and surname? It's long story, myquestion is how to avoid that because I'm sure that there is a solution

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your comments I believe that you confuse username with first and last name. Your users may have same first and last name, but they must not have the same username. FOSUserBundle uses username/password combination to authenticate users. With some configuration you may allow users to login with email/password, or even use email as username.

In any case username is supposed to stay unique. If you configured FOSUserBundle properly, you should have your own user entity class that extends user entity from the bundle. That is where you add additional fields, such as first and last name, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow multiple users to have the same username, what you will need to do is override the FOSUserBundle controller and set a new field in the registration page.  I would recommend removing the 'username' field and create your new 'name' property.

So add a name called 'user_name' which acts the same way as first name and last name.  Remove the username field from the registration form as this has to be unique.

You can learn more about this here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html

When a user is created using FOSUserBundle they must require the username, email and password.  Because you have removed the username field, I would just duplicate the email as the username (because you need at least one field that is unique).

If you override the login form so that it only checks for email and password for validation rather than username/email and password, it should give you your desired functionality of logging in via email and password only.  As username will also be their email.

Example of the new registration page when you have overridden the form vs stock registration form

Old:

```
Email: email@address.com
Username: uniquename
Password: xxxxxxx
Repeat password: xxxxxxx
```

New:

```
Email: email@address.com
User_name: duplicatesallowed
Password: xxxxxxx
Repeat password: xxxxxxx
```

Modify the controller so user.username takes value of user.email (because emails will be unique).